# JAVA JTable adding new rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, addition

I'm trying to add new rows to JTable from database, but no rows there adds.
Here's the way I trying to do that:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) pagrindinis.visos_skolos_table.getModel();

model.addRow(new Object[]{"TESTAS", "1000"});
model.addRow(new Object[]{"TESTAS2", "2000"});
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have ane exceptions? post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: I solved it with this:

DefaultTableModel y = (DefaultTableModel) MyTable.getModel();
Vector rowData = new Vector();

rowData.add(data);
y.addRow(rowData);